# C# how to display datetimepicker control for all rows of gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

In my application I am creating rows and columns dynamically. I created a column of type System.DateTime. After this i want to display datetimepicker control for all rows in that column.

I created a column using

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("CreatedOn", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
```

and i am adding rows as

```
foreach(String filename ......)
 dataTable_FileProperty.Rows.Add(filename,//here i want to add dateTimePicker
```

So, what is a solution for this.

**EDIT:** Please provide some code snippet. I am new to C#.net.

Thanks.

Comment: @ronny: DateTimePicker is a System.Windows.Forms control. Maybe you need asp:Calendar? (from System.Web.UI.WebControls)

Comment: @abatishchev: I am creating Windows.Forms application.

Comment: I see. I was confused by tags 'asp.net' and 'gridview' you set first. My solution is about web application. Though I hope you will find something useful for your case.

Answer (score 2):

By default you have just these columns available for you:

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, DataGridViewImageColumn, DataGridViewButtonColumn, DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, DataGridViewLinkColumn

If you want to show a datetimepicker control then you have to implement a custom column.

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use the item template of the gridview and place a datetimepicker there. A good example is [here](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3609991)

For implementing it you have to implement the `ITemplate` interface.

Another example is [this](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/168_Create_Dynamic_GridView_Control_in_C_ASPNet.aspx)

An easy implementation of it is given in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx). But the code is in VB.net.

Comment: The solution provided by you is so complex. I am waiting for easy one. anyways Thanks. :)

Comment: i have updated an easy implementation link of msdn. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Rows` contains data, i.e file name, date, some strings.

`GridView.Columns` contains controls to display data.

So if you're using [DataRowCollection.Add(Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) :

```
DataTable DataTable1 = new DataTable();
DataTable1.Columns.AddRange(
     new DataColumn[] {
          new DataColumn("file", typeof(string)),
          new DataColumn("date", typeof(DateTime)) });

foreach (string f in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\windows"))
    DataTable1.Rows.Add(f, System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(f));

GridView1.DataSource = DataTable1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And the markup of `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File" DataField="file" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Calendar1" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("date") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Also you need to read more about [Calendar.SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx) and [Calendar.VisibleDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate.aspx)